# Citrix Xen Server 5.6: Virtual Machines (VM) Deleted or Gone Missing?

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, xen

In my environment I have a Citrix Xen Server (ver 5.6) with multiple VM's setup in my lab on a local partition mount. I arrived to my lab setup last week to find that my VM's have gone missing. The local mount shows no data, as if someone logged in and deleted my VM's. The server was online and not powered off.

My question is: with the local logs under the Host (/var/logs) is there any way to tell that the VM was deleted, or to tell that some other issue caused the server to go missing? For example, could I analyze xensource.log to verify that a VM was removed/deleted from the host? Or, is there another log that could verify why my VMs have gone missing?

At first glance, I thought the missing servers was caught in "limbo", such as, a reboot happened and now they are hung up and need to be shut down in via console. So, I ran the following command:

```
xe vm-list resident-o​n=<UUID of the XenServer host> --multiple
```

However, the result of this command is blank. I have checked the partition where the data was hosted, and it is empty. I do not have any hardware failures (no failed disks or RAID issues).

Any ideas on a way to verify what happened to my missing VM's?? Any help is much appreciated, and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several commands may help you identify your trouble:

```
history
cat /var/log/messages
cat /var/log/xenstored-access.log
mount -o remount /dev/sdx
df -h
```

Comment: The xenstored-access and xensource logs showed exactly what happened, along with the other logs, thanks for your help!